# Complex Power series with factorials

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Find the radius of convergence of 
$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{n!}$$
 $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty {(-1)^nz^{n(n+1)}}/{n}$$
What is the behavior of the series for $z=1, -1,i$

Answer (score 1):

$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty z^{n!}\leq\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty z^n<\infty$ for $0\!<\!z\!<\!1$, but $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty 1^{n!}=\infty$, therefore the radius of convergence is $1$.

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left|\frac{(-1)^n}nz^{n(n+1)}\right|\leq\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}z^{n(n+1)}\leq\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty z^n<\infty$ for $0\!<\!z\!<\!1$, but $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left|\frac{(-1)^n}n1^{n(n+1)}\right|=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n=\infty$, so the radius of convergence is also $1$.

What was needed:

- The geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$ is convergent for $|z|<1$.
- The harmonic series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n$ is divergent.
- Absolute convergence implies regular convergence.
- Every power series has a circle of convergence inside which it's absolutely convergent and is divergent outside.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I want to ask one more thing. What is the behavior of the second series for $z=1, -1,i$

Comment: @Malik $1$ and $-1$ are same, because $n(n+1)$ is always even and it converges because of [Leibniz's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_criterion). As for $i$ (or $-i$), $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{2n}}{2n}i^{2n(2n+1)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n}$ converges for the same reason, so the even partial sums of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}ni^{n(n+1)}$ converge and therefore the whole sum converges, because odd partial sums differ by $\frac{(-1)^{2n+1}}{2n+1}i^{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.